# DRF - Custom serializer - prefill data by request.user

Tags: python, django, django-models, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have a model:

```
class Income(...):
    user = ForeignKey(User....) # not null
    type = ...
    amount = ...
```

And a special non-model serializer that should (besides other things) create `Income` objects for this user.

```
class WelcomeWizardSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    applicant = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
    applicant_incomes = IncomeSerializer(many=True, required=True)
```

Obviously, I need to tell `IncomeSerializer` to use `applicant` as `user`.
Otherwise `WelcomeWizardSerializer` returns errors:

```
{'applicant_incomes': [{'user': [ErrorDetail(string='Toto pole je povinné.', code='required')]}, {'user': [ErrorDetail(string='Toto pole je povinné.', code='required')]}]}
```

How can I do that?

```
@action(['POST'], detail=False, url_path='from-welcome-wizard')
def from_welcome_wizard(self, request, pk=None):
    serializer = WelcomeWizardSerializer(context={'request':request}, data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid(): # not valid
        serializer.save()
```

I know I should get `applicant` (as I don't want to use `CurrentUserDefault` in `IncomeSerializer`) and add it to the `data['incomes']` objects but I don't know where/when is the right place/time.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the error message, you have an issue with `WelcomeWizardSerializer.applicant_incomes`, not `WelcomeWizardSerializer.applicant`. `WelcomeWizardSerializer.applicant` is all right.

Apparently, you have a `user` field inside `applicant_incomes`, and you don't want a client to pass a `user` into it as well. So you need to replace `IncomeSerializer` with some new serializer, for example, `IncomeDefaultUserSerializer`. You will need a similar `HiddenField` inside it, like:

```py
user = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
```

After that, you have to use `IncomeDefaultUserSerializer` inside `WelcomeWizardSerializer`, and your issue has to be solved.